# How to fetch data from MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am trying to use Express + MongoDB building React app.

I was able to post some documents to MongoDB. Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to print fetched data to the screen.

I have these routes:

```
router.post('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    const totalBalance = new TotalBalanceModelTemplate({
        totalBalance:request.body.totalBalance,
    });
    totalBalance.save()
    .then(data => {
        response.json(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        response.json(error);
    });
});

router.get('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    TotalBalanceModelTemplate.find(request.body.totalBalance, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return error
        } else {
            response.json(data[0])
        }
    })
});
```

This is axios request:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        const resp = axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance');

        console.log(resp);
    }, []);
```

It returns a promise that has a parameter `data` which equals to object value which is the first value in the array

```
data: {_
    id: "60c48b4ec60919553d92319f", 
    totalBalance: 5555, 
    __v: 0
}
```

and prints it out to the console.

How can I print out to the console the value `totalBalance` instead of whole promise?

By the way, sometime the array of `data` is empty (there are no documents in the DB), how should i handle these cases as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Axios GET method does not have any request body. But you are trying to use it in the MongoDB query. - "TotalBalanceModelTemplate.find(request.body.totalBalance, (error, data) => {".

The find query should be object {}. If require pass on conditions to it.

First point, to print only "totalBalance" output. Use, console.log(resp.totalBalance);

Second point, to handle records length, have a if else condition,

```
    if (error) {
       return error
    } else if (data.length) {
       return response.send("No records found")
    } else {
       response.json(data[0])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chandra! Your suggestion for handling records length worked for me, I used:

`else if (data.length === 0) { return response.send("No records found" } `

Comment: However, I cannot use console.log(resp.totalBalance) to print only "totalBalance" output since axios request is in another file, I get an error **Property 'totalBalance' does not exist on type 'Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>'.**

Comment: Now I have a clear information about error, where it is throwing. Try to handle axios response by adding await.

useEffect(async () => {
        const resp = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance');
        console.log(resp. totalBalance);
    }, []);

Comment: I'm trying to use it this way ()  `useEffect(() => {
        const fetchDataAsync = async () => {
           await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
           .then(result => console.log(result.data[0]))
        }   
        fetchDataAsync();
    }, []);`

However, the code above prints out `undefined` even though I have documents in my MongoDB.

(I am using slightly different syntax than in your comment because I use Typescript and by using your code I was getting a TS error "type ‘() => Promise<void>’ is not assignable to parameter of type ‘EffectCallback’.")

Comment: console.log(result) is enough to print the response. No need of fetching the array first position. Because its already handled in  API routes.

Comment: What I want to ultimately achieve is to assign fetched data to the state of a component. I have just modified the function and it works when there are some documents in the database. How could I add a validation if there is at least on document in MongoDB so that the app would not crash overwise?

My current function:
`useEffect(() => {
        const resp = async () => {
           await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
           .then(result => setInsertedValue(result.data[0].totalBalance))
        }   
        resp();
    }, []);`

Comment: Change your setInsertedValue method, to handle app crashing. From "setInsertedValue(result.data[0].totalBalance)" to 
"setInsertedValue(((result.data || [])[0] || {}).totalBalance || 0)"

Comment: I didn't know that validation can be done this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Routes**

```
router.post("/totalbalance", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const totalBalance = new TotalBalanceModelTemplate({
        totalBalance: req.body.totalBalance,
    })
    await totalBalance.save();
    res.json(totalBalance)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message
    })
  }
})

router.get("/totalbalance", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const totalBalances = await TotalBalanceModelTemplate.find();
    res.json(totalBalances)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message
    })
  }
})
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance');
      await setData(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data <= 0 ? (
        <div className="empty">
          <p>No data!</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        data.map((d) => (
          <ul key={d.id}>
            <li>{d.totalBalance}</li>
          </ul>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```