# How to get 'data' property value of a promise

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, http, axios, get

I am using Express + MongoDB to build a React app.

I'm trying to figure out how to assign fetched data to the state of a component.

I have this route:

```
router.get('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    TotalBalanceModelTemplate.find(request.totalBalance, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return error
        } else if (data.length === 0) {
            return response.send("No records found")
        } else {
            response.json(data[0])
        }
    })
});
```

This is axios request (located in another file) and a setter/getter of the state:

```
const [insertedValue, setInsertedValue] = useState<string>("");

useEffect(() => {
   const resp = axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
       .then(result => result.data);

   setInsertedValue(resp);
}, []);
```

cont "resp" equals to a promise that has a parameter "data" which equals to `data: {_id: "60c48b4ec60919553d92319f", totalBalance: 5555, __v: 0}`.

How can I extract the value `resp.totalBalance` and, for example, assign it to a variable?

Currently `setInsertedValue(resp)` gives an error `Argument of type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'`.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data from MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947969/how-to-fetch-data-from-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your .json - visualised:

It have 3 properties - and only 1 nesting level.

[image]

Access to that data:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    
        useEffect(() => {
           const resp = axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
               .then((result) => {
                 if(result.data.length > 1) {
                   setData(result.data)
                 }
                else{
                   console.log('empty response)'
                }
                )};
           setInsertedValue(resp);
        }, []);
```

in this code saving whole **object** to the **data state**.

to access specific property there is need to:

1. data._id = first value
2. data.totalBalance = second value
3. data.__v = third value

---

There is possibility to save only totalBalance:

const [totalBalance, setTotalBalance] = useState();

```
useEffect(() => {
   const resp = axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
       .then(result => setTotalBalance(result.data[0].totalBalance));

   setInsertedValue(resp);
}, []);
```

where 0 - is the number of object - in this case it's first object from array. It can be looped for storing all totalBalances from x objects.

Comment: Your explanation help me a lot! However, this approach works only then there are some documents in the database. How could I add a validation if there is at least on document in MongoDB so that the app would not crash overwise?