# Validating if there are any documents in MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, async-await, axios, get

How to validate if there are any documents in MongoDB before trying to assign fetched value to a React state?

I have this function:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const resp = async () => {
           await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
           .then(
               result => setInsertedValue(result.data[0].totalBalance))
        }   
        resp();
    }, []);
```

It works fine when there is at least 1 document in the DB. How could I add a validation to check if there is at least on document in MongoDB so that the app would not crash otherwise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question is how to make sure `result.data` has content in it before setting the react state,

One way to make sure the app does not crash by using a default value(-1 in the code) when no documents are returned:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const resp = async () => {
       await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
       .then(
           result => setInsertedValue(result.data && result.data.length>0 ? result.data[0].totalBalance : -1))
    }   
    resp();
}, []);
```

In case the default value messes with your output(for ex, -1 is a valid inserted value), it would be better to use a default value of `null` and tackle the condition in the render.

An example would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const resp = async () => {
       await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
       .then(
           result => setInsertedValue(result.data && result.data.length>0 ? result.data[0].totalBalance : null))
    }   
    resp();
}, []);

return (
<>
{
  insertedValue === null ? <p> no data found </p> :<p></p> // logic when documents exists.
}
</>
);
```

Here, we default `insertedValue = null` in case there is no data from mongoDB and render the component to alert, no documents from mongodb found. In the case of when there are documents found, the code runs as normal!

Hope this fixes your issue, apologies in advanced if this confused you more. Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. It works and is really useful. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: @grubbyGerbil If you are satisfied with the answer, tag it "useful". You formulated 3 questions for in fact only 1 issue and each time you didn't have the respect to validate the proposed answers ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947969/how-to-fetch-data-from-mongodb, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949131/how-to-get-data-property-value-of-a-promise.

Comment: I'm totally new to stackoverflow, I guess, I've just tagged it as useful, thanks!